# Switch every pair of words in a string (“ab cd ef gh ijk” becomes “cd ab gh ef ijk”) in c/c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Switch every pair of words in a string (“ab cd ef gh ijk” becomes “cd ab gh ef ijk”) in c++ without any library function.

```
int main(){
char s[]="h1 h2 h3 h4";//sample input
switch_pair(s);
std::cout<<s;
    return 0;
}

char * switch_pair(char *s){
char * pos = s;
char * ptr = s;
int sp = 0;//counts number of space
while(*pos){
    if(*pos==' ' && ++sp==2){ //if we hit a space and it is second space then we've a pair
        revStr_iter(ptr,pos-1);//reverse the pair so 'h1 h2' -> '2h 1h'
        sp=0;//set no. of space to zero to hunt new pairs
        ptr=pos+1;//reset ptr to nxt word after the pair i.e. h3'
    }
    pos++;
}
if(sp==1) //tackle the case where input is 'h1 h2' as only 1 space is there
    revStr_iter(ptr,pos-1);
revWord(s); //this will reverse each individual word....i hoped so :'(
return s;
 }

 char* revStr_iter(char* l,char * r){//trivial reverse string algo
char * p = l;
while(l<r){
    char c = *l;
    *l = *r;
    *r = c;
    l++;
    r--;
} 
return p;
 }


char* revWord(char* s){//this is the villain....need to fix it...Grrrr
char* pos = s;
char* w1 = s;
while(*pos){
    if(*pos==' '){//reverses each word before space
        revStr_iter(w1,pos-1);
        w1=pos+1;
    }
pos++;
}
return s;
}
```

Input - h1 h2 h3 h4
expected - h2 h1 h4 h3
actual - h2 h1 h3 **4h**

can any noble geek soul help plz :(((

Comment: What should happen if the list contains an odd number of words? Or if a pair of words is separated by more than one space?

Comment: in case of odd number of words...the last odd word is left as it is..so h1 h2 h3 will be output as h2 h1 h3
multiple spaces or tabs can be tackled easily by just putting an if condition which will increment the pointer till we get a whitespace...

Comment: What about consecutive spaces? I.e.: `"h1<space><space>h2"`?

Comment: use && to check if the next cell does not contain spaces. (... && String[n] != ' ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int Groups = 1; // Count 1 for the first group of letters
for ( int Loop1 = 0; Loop1 < strlen(String); Loop1++)
  if (String[Loop1] == ' ') // Any extra groups are delimited by space
    Groups += 1;

int* GroupPositions = new int[Groups]; // Stores the positions
for ( int Loop2 = 0, Position = 0; Loop2 < strlen(String); Loop2++)
{
  if (String[Loop2] != ' ' && (String[Loop2-1] == ' ' || Loop2-1 < 0))
  {
    GroupPositions[Position] = Loop2; // Store position of the first letter
    Position += 1; // Increment the next position of interest
  }
}
```

If you can't use strlen, write a function that counts any letters until it encounters a null terminator '\0'.

Comment: This is cool...finally i was also able to write a function which did it...thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

IMO, what you're working on so far looks/seems a lot more like C code than C++ code. I think I'd start from something like:

1. break the input into word objects
2. swap pairs of word objects
3. re-construct string of rearranged words

For that, I'd probably define a really minimal string class. Just about all it needs (for now) is the ability to create a string given a pointer to char and a length (or something on that order), and the ability to assign (or swap) strings.

I'd also define a tokenizer. I'm not sure if it should really be a function or a class, but for the moment, let's jut say "function". All it does is look at a string and find the beginning and end of a word, yielding something like a pointer to the beginning, and the length of the word.

Finally, you need/want an array to hold the words. For a first-step, you could just use a normal array, then later when/if you want to have the array automatically expand as needed, you can write a small class to handle it.